# How to Increment Seek bar value

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to create seekbar that is divided into 5 section poor , `below Average` `Average` and `Excellent` , for every step i want increment like this seekbar 
Default=0
max value = 100;

```
i want seek bar values like this :0,25,50,75,100
```

how can i achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to just update the `onProgressChanged` method as follows.

```
int yourStep = 25;
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
progress = ((int)Math.round(progress/yourStep ))*yourStep;
seekBar.setProgress(progress);
textview.setText(progress + "");

}
```

Hope its help

**UPD**

I think in your xml you set  `android:max="100"` for your `SeekBar`. But you need to set `android:max="101"`, because between `0` and `100` = `101` point's.

just replace

```
android:max="100"
```

for

```
android:max="101"
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Check it. I create test app and all works great.

Comment: Great  work thanks, i increment it with int yourStep = 20; to get 5 section of seek bar

Comment: Why bother creating a step value? See my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
seekBar.setProgress(4);
```

This will give the values, `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. You don't need to be playing about with `onProgressChanged`, simply multiply by 25 and you have the values `0, 25, 50, 75, 100`.

Comment: this is wrong. if you dont change the max Value, this will give you values of form: 0,4,8,12,16,...,92,96,100. what you need to change is `seekBar.setMax(4)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
seekBar.setProgress(YOUR_VALUE);
```