# Increment Seekbar progress by 25% with textview display 25%

Tags: android, seekbar

I am using seek bar in my application.I can increment the progress with 25% and show it on text view. But what exactly I want is that I need that seek bar progress is also increase by 25% but it only increase by as usual. It increase with 1% only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use API of `SeekBar` class :

> public synchronized void setProgress (int progress)
>   Added in API level 1
>
> Set the current progress to the specified value. Does not do anything
>   if the progress bar is in indeterminate mode.
>
> Parameters progress   the new progress, between 0 and getMax()

Comment: How it can possible can you explain more. Because it only increase progress value not SEEKBAR progress. GEt IT.?

Comment: It changes value on `seekbar`. Is not it?

Comment: I want that when I drag the seek bar from left to right. The progress of seek bar should be increment 25%. And When I drag the seek bar from right to left the seek bar should be decrement by 25%. Not only progress. But step wise progress also.

Comment: Seek bar changed with 1% only as its usual behaviour.

Comment: Solution is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272053/how-to-increment-seek-bar-value..